# Replace two numbers in a column with 99

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have Selling Price which is not in proper format as its converted from Dollar to our local currency.

So the amount in the column are ending with random number. I want to change last two numbers to 99.

For Eg.

```
324
2344
3322
234
```

I want to change this to

```
399
2399
3399
299
```

Can anyone help with some formula to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)&"99")
```

The `LEFT` grabs the digits to left of the last two digits, and `VALUE` converts the whole thing from a string to a number. This assumes that all your numbers are at least two digits long.

Comment: Thank you so much... It will save me lot of time.. Thanks